# How do you create a Mutation which has a Union as a field with AWS AppSync / DynamoDB (React Native)

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have worked out how to create a new user and write basic fields to DynamoDB like the name of the user (string) but I can't find a way to have a Union as one of the inputs.

In my example when the user registers I want to know what type of user is using the app: Either it will be a teach or a student (and the app will use this info to display different UI depending on the type of user)

I haven't found any examples of this so maybe it's impossible? Has anyone done this? Does anyone know if you can do it? Or maybe I shouldn't be trying to save this as a Union...

I am using react-native, AWS Amplify, AppSync, Cognito.

My schema:

```
type User
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  userTypes: [UserType]
}

union UserType = Teacher | Student
```

The code generated mutation:

```
const registerUser = `mutation RegisterUser($input: CreateUserInput!) {
  registerUser(input: $input) {
    id
    name
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    userTypes {
      ... on Teacher {
        id
        name
        subjectsTaught
      }
      ... on Student {
        id
        name
        lessons
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Then the actual react native part:

```
try {
            await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(registerUser,
                { input: { name: "Tamsyn", userTypes: { Student } } } ));
                console.log('created user');
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('error creating user', err);
            }
```

Comment: [Amplify does not generate input types properly when ```union``` is used](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/266#issuecomment-520974157). How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use an enum like this:

```
type User
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  userType: [UserType]
}

enum UserType {
  Teacher
  Student
}
```

And then when the user signs up I can call this if they select "Teacher":

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, { input: { name: name, userType: 'Teacher' } }));
```

or if the user selects student I can call...

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, { input: { name: name, userType: 'Student' } }));
```

And then when the user is in the app if I want to find out which profile to display:

```
   if (user.userType === 'Teacher') {
       navigation.navigate('TeacherProfile');
     } else if (user.userType === 'Student') {
       navigation.navigate('StudentProfile');
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Union in graphQL Queries(https://graphql.org/learn/schema/) and (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/)

However the issue is *input Unions* are not supported for Mutations. Specifically, this section of code is correct

```
userTypes {
  ... on Teacher {
    id
    name
    subjectsTaught
  }
  ... on Student {
    id
    name
    lessons
  }
}
```

What I believe is not working for you is the following code section because you are trying to pass a *Union* in as an input. A Mutation cannot take a union as an input.

```
`mutation RegisterUser($input: CreateUserInput!) { registerUser(input: $input){...}
```

Mutations can only take Scalar types or a special type called *Input*, which can be a mapped object but all of the internal fields **have to be** Scalar types.

So you cannot use Unions for Mutations. In fact, I don't agree with the example from LxL, you should separate your mutation schema defined types to all be *Input* type, and then use the Union for querying.

A potential solution to this is to use an Enum type for Teacher/Student and flatten the types into one *Input* type and then handle the difference in the resolver if there are different fields.